# Applying NonAction to controller method according to implemented interfaces

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, reflection, attributes

Here is my synchronisation controller, it allows to push and/or pull data.

```
public class SyncController : MyController
{
  ISyncable _sync;

  public SyncController(ISyncable sync) { _sync = sync; }

  [HttpPost, PullAction]
  public async Task<IActionResult> pull()
  {
    (_sync as IPullable).Pull();
  }

  [HttpPost, PushAction]
  public async Task<IActionResult> push()
  {
    (_sync as IPushable).Push();
  }
}
```

If `ISyncable` implements `IPushable`, controller shall provide the `push` method`.

If `ISyncable` implements `IPullable`, controller shall provide the `pull` method`.

So I'd like to apply `[NonAction]` attribute according to implemented interfaces.

I intend to do it with custom attributes:

```
[AttributeUsage(validOn: AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class PushActionAttribute : Attribute
{
    public PushActionAttribute([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        Type syncType = ???;  // TODO get ISyncable type from propertyName
        bool isPushable = typeof(IPushable).IsAssignableFrom(syncType);

        if(!isPushable)
        {
          // TODO apply NonActionAttribute
        }
    }
}

[AttributeUsage(validOn: AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class PullActionAttribute : Attribute
{
    public PullActionAttribute([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        Type syncType = ???;  // TODO get ISyncable type from propertyName
        bool isPullable = typeof(IPullable).IsAssignableFrom(syncType);

        if(!isPullable)
        {
          // TODO apply NonActionAttribute
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to retrieve syncType from attribute target?

Is it possible to apply `[NonAction]` attribute dynamically?

Is there a better way to implement this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Can you simply do:

```cs
if (_sync is IPullable) (_sync as IPullable).Pull();
```

?
No added complexity of reflection, attributes and other boilerplate. I don't think there is a dynamic/runtime way of adding attributes of disabling methods.

You could return `NotFound` if it fails, e.g.

```cs
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult push()
{
    if (_sync is IPushable) (_sync as IPushable).Push();
    else return NotFound();
    return View();
}
```

(removed `async Task`, as there's no `await` or returned `Task`)...

Comment: I already do that, but as I share the swagger doc, I don't want these methods to be visible or available. I suppose I could filter the swagger doc but it would just be a fig leaf.

Comment: @sinsedrix AFAIK attributes like `ConditionalAttribute` and `NonActionAttribute` are flags for the _compiler_ i.e. they need to be known at compile time. Just look at their sources ([here](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/diagnostics/conditionalattribute.cs) and [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/NonActionAttribute.cs))... they're practically empty! I know of no dynamic way to disable methods.